# Laravel 5.5 Job with delay fires instantly instead of waiting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

In my application I am dispatching a job on work queue with delay time. But its work instantly not waiting for delay time. In my config and eve I am using driver as database.

In my database job table not insert any job till now.

My config:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database')
```

My controller code:

```
Log::info('Request Status Check with Queues Begins', __METHOD__);
MyGetInfo::dispatch($this->name,$this->password,$this->id,$trr->id)->onQueue('work')->delay(12);
return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: check `.env` file what is the value of `QUEUE_DRIVER`

Comment: delay work inserted into job table now but queue not process after delay time passed @Ben

Answer (score 0):

The value of `QUEUE_DRIVER` must be set to `database` in .env file.
make sure to run this afterwards:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

also run

```
php artisan queue:listen
```